# how to get the number in second column and second row or return a default value

Tags: regex, linux, grep

im stuck with grep please tell me a regex solution to get the number in second column of second row

what im trying to get the pid only for the listen port

```
lsof -i:43458 |grep LISTEN
```

AND GOT

```
skype   2680 orangehrm   85u  IPv4  17151      0t0  TCP *:43458 (LISTEN)
```

but just for my knowledge i also need to know how to get the row

sample data

```
COMMAND  PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
skype   2680 orangehrm   85u  IPv4  17151      0t0  TCP *:43458 (LISTEN)

skype   2680 orangehrm   86u  IPv4  17152      0t0  UDP *:43458
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: 2680 just the number if the number doesnt exist null

Comment: `lsof -i:43458 | awk '/LISTEN/{print $2}'`

Comment: thanks it works but how to get in case of multiple rows

Comment: That will work for multiple rows

Comment: `lsof -i:43458 | awk '/LISTEN/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/{print $2}'`

Comment: thanks go ahead post it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below awk command would print the second column if,

1. The line must contain the string `LISTEN`
2. Second column must contain one or more digits

   ```
   lsof -i:43458 | awk '/LISTEN/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/{print $2}'
   ```

**Example:**

```
$ cat f
foo 123 LISTEN
foo bar LISTEN
$ awk '/LISTEN/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/{print $2}' f
123
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using [`tr`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tr%201) and [`cut`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut):

```
lsof -i:43458 | grep LISTEN | tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f 2
```

The `tr` is used to remove any additional space between words.
The `cut` is used to select the field you want (here the second one).